# problem when start using cpuminer / cudaminer

Tags: litecoin, miner-configuration

I got this in the CMD :

cgminer.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I have downloaded cpuminer and cudaminer to mine LTC with my labtop (core i7, Nvidia GT 525 M)

using www.wemineltc.com  pool

but when I double click the .bat  file (cmd flash for a sec)  then nothing happen

can someone  help me please ?

i  have used this tutorial : https://teksyndicate.com/forum/litecoin/guide-mining-nvidia-now-guide-mining-feathercoin/137688

Answer (score 1):

I think that you configured the batch file incorrectly. It seems as if your batch file is beginning with a call to cgminer when either

A) You don't even have cgminer installed, you didn't mention installing it whatsoever. Download cgminer, and relocate the batch file in the application directory.

B) Your batch file calls cgminer, and it can't find it. Either move the batch file to the cgminer application directory for cgminer, or go in and edit the batch file to call either 'cpuminer' or 'cudaminer' (this should be the first word in the file) depending on which .exe you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

edit your batch file for correct info, this is mine

cudaminer.exe -o stratum+tcp://world.wemineltc.com:3334 -O Iron_Mafia.1:x

with Iron_Mafia.1 being my workers name

then :

then x being my password

Answer (score 0):

This is windows telling you it doesn't know where the `cudaminer` program is. One fix would be to move your batch file into the folder where cudaminer is located. For instance, mine is `C:\Users\....\Desktop\cudaminer-2013-12-10\x64`
(would be ...`\x86` if you are on 32 bit windows)

Oh, I see you are trying to use Cgminer. Fix is the same, just figure out where cgminer is located and put the batch file there.

Alternately, you could add the cgminer directory to Windows PATH statement, but it is probably already quite long.